# How to parse time string without offset using Moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a special use case where application always has to use time in `America/Chicago` timezone. So I have set Moment default timezone to be `moment.tz.setDefault("America/Chicago");`.

With this setup, I send all the Date-time inputs from client to server in `America/Chicago` timezone in js format `MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A`. And whenever client requests the time field, server returns the time in `America/Chicago` timezone and in the same format.

Now there is a case where I have to parse this Date-time value returned by server and compare it with current `America/Chicago` time. I tried this,

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Chicago");

let now = moment();

// serverResponse is America/Chicago datetime string in format MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A

let serverResponseMoment = moment(serverResponse);

// The above statement is where I am facing issue. Since the users could be from
// anywhere, moment(serverResponse) will be assuming the serverResponse string to
// be of the local timezone as there is no offset part attached to the string.

return now.isBefore(serverResponseMoment);
```

Also tried

```
let serverResponseMoment = moment.tz(serverResponse,"America/Chicago");

// The above statement assumes the serverResponse to be in UTC and give me an "America/Chicago"
// date-time after conversion
```

I have also tried `moment.utc(serverResponse)`. All parsing fails when the last condition check is executed.

What I want is a moment instance, in already set default timezone, holding my `serverResponse` as underlying DateTime.

Or some statement that does this

`Hey Moment, serverResponse is already in "America/Chicago" timezone, you don't have to make any sort of timezone assumptions. Just parse it and return an instance of yourself`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of `moment.js`? Do you use `moment-timezone.js`?

Comment: @fen1x I am using "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21" which installed moment 2.24 as dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know timezone and string format - you can create your own `serverResponse` parser:

```js
const momentParserFactory = (format, tz) => (str) => moment.tz(str, format, tz);
const chicagoMoment = momentParserFactory('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A', 'America/Chicago');

let now = moment();
let serverResponse_1 = '10/07/2019 11:40 AM';
let serverResponseMoment_1 = chicagoMoment(serverResponse_1);

console.log(`"Now" is: ${now.format()}`)
console.log(`Server response date 1: ${serverResponseMoment_1.format()}`);
console.log(`"Now" is before server response date 1: ${now.isBefore(serverResponseMoment_1)}`);

let serverResponse_2 = '10/09/2020 4:20 AM';
let serverResponseMoment_2 = chicagoMoment(serverResponse_2);

console.log(`Server response date 2: ${serverResponseMoment_2.format()}`);
console.log(`"Now" is before server response date 2: ${now.isBefore(serverResponseMoment_2)}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted `moment.tz("10/07/2019 11:40 AM",'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A', 'America/Chicago')`. I needed to solve this yesterday. So I rewrote the server side to sent the time in RFC format. So timezone is already there in moment input string and thus all my warnings and bugs were fixed even if I had to put some extra work :) Thank you